# Visual studio trying to load pdb file when starting the application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I'm running into a trouble when i try to start an asmx WebService in Visual Studio where i can't simply initialize the service, an exception is thrown "stackoverflow exception" and it's saying the System.Web.pdb/System.Runtime.Serialization is not loaded.

Checking the Module's window , i can see that most of the dlls are with Symbol Status "Cannot find or open the PDB file" but the own dll of the project, that the PDB file is correctly loaded.

If i right click and then select "Load Symbols", Visual Studio automatically loads many dll's pdbs, appointing to some temporary directory and the error keeps going, but now, Visual Studio just says "Source information is missing from the debug information for this module".

Checking the bin folder, there is only the WebService pdb(and i think that's the right).

I have tryed Enabling/Disabling "Enable Just My Code" in Symbol's options, Enabling to load the pdb files from Microsoft Symbols Server(just to check if the error's gone) but not happend.

Any other advice for this situation?

I have just checked that this only happend when the web service(.asmx) is running on IIS Express. If i run in visual studio 2010, but instead of choosing IIS Express, i check the Visual Studio Development Server, it works well.
The only thing that is messing me up, is because it was working pretty well 2 days ago.

Comment: This is entirely normal, just notifications from the debugger that it will not know how to display source code for the .NET Framework.  Right-click the Output window and untick "Module Load Messages" if you don't want to look at them.  Do focus on debugging your own code instead of framework code.

Comment: @HansPassant, i have updated my question.
It is only happening when the web service is running on iis express(idk why it is happening because it ever worked) .